# Exercise involving topological vector spaces, linear maps, and the quotient map

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm doing a homework problem out of Rudin's $\textit{Functional Analysis}$ which is basically a proof of which I have completed some of it, but I'm not sure about the rest of it. Without further ado, here it is:

Suppose $X, Y$ are topological vector spaces, $\Lambda: X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear map, $N$ is a closed subspace of $X$, $\pi: X \rightarrow X/N$ is the quotient map, and $\Lambda x=0$ $\forall x \in N$.

We are asked to prove the following:
$(1)$  There is a unique $f: X/N \rightarrow Y$ such that $\Lambda x = f(\pi(x))$ $\forall x \in X$.
$(2)$ The map $f$ is linear.
$(3)$ $\Lambda$ is continuous iff $f$ is continuous.
$(4)$ $\Lambda$ is an open map iff $f$ is an open map.

So far, I was able to prove $(3)$. To prove $(3)$ since $N$ is closed, by Theorem $1.41$(a) on  p. $29$ of Rudin, we have that the quotient map $\pi$ is continuous. Also, the composition of continuous maps is continuous, so if $f$ is continuous, then so is $\Lambda = f \circ \pi$. The converse holds since $\pi$ is an open map by Theorem $1.41$(a). What I'm not so sure about is the proof for $(1)$, $(2)$, and half of the proof for $(4)$. One direction is clear for $(4)$ in that since $\pi$ is an open map and the composition of open maps is an open map, if $f$ is an open map, then so is $\Lambda$. It is the other direction which is given me some trouble, or maybe it might be something obvious which I'm just missing. I would appreciate some guidance for those parts that I haven't been able to prove yet.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}$ is not a function.

Comment: How come that's true?

Comment: Well, $\pi^{-1} \colon \mathfrak{P}(X/N) \to \mathfrak{P}(X)$ is a function ;) $\pi^{-1}$ associates subsets of $X/N$ to their preimages under $\pi$.

Comment: $\pi$ is not injective, so its inverse is not a well-defined map.

Comment: My apologies, Daniel, but what is that symbol you are using?

Comment: Power set. Would $P(X)$ be the symbol you're familiar with?

Comment: Alright, if $\pi^{-1}$ is not a function, what is the alternative to prove that $f$ is linear?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes.

Comment: Have you ever proved that for a group homomorphism $\varphi \colon G \to H$ with kernel $N$ you have an induced homomorphism $\overline{\varphi} \colon G/N \to H$? It's the same proof (mutatis mutandis).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Unfortunately, I have not. I have yet to do graduate algebra.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you change the domain of $\pi^{-1}.$ The composition $\Lambda\circ \pi^{-1}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @azarel We can give it meaning by abusing notation (that's quite often done). But as you rightly observed, $\pi^{-1}$ is not a function $X/N \to X$ (unless $N = \{0\}$), so $\Lambda\circ \pi^{-1}$ doesn't conventionally make sense anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since $N$ is in the kernel of of $\Lambda$, the first isomorphism theorem guarantees the existence and unicity of $f$. It also guarantees that $f$ is linear.

Now, for (4), if $\Lambda$ is open and $U$ is open in $X/N$, then by definition of the quotient topology, $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, so that $\Lambda(\pi^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. But $\Lambda(\pi^{-1}(U)) = f(\pi(\pi^{-1}(U)) = f(U)$. So $f$ is open.

Comment: I conclude that the uniqueness and linearity of $f$ is implied by $N$ being the kernel of the linear map $\Lambda$ and the first isomorphism theorem. So that takes care of the proofs of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @Libertron Well $N$ is not necessarily the entire kernel, but that only means that the induced map might not be injective. What's important is that $N$ is contained inside the kernel.